# Variable getting released between calls

Tags: ios, objective-c, theos, logos

I am developing a tweak for iOS using Logos/Theos.

I need to store the last two characters the user has typed in at all times.

My code for this is:

```
static NSString *lastTwoChars = [[NSString alloc] init];
...
if (lastTwoChars.length < 2) {
    lastTwoChars = [lastTwoChars stringByAppendingString:text];
} else {
    lastTwoChars = [lastTwoChars stringByAppendingString:text];
    lastTwoChars = [lastTwoChars substringFromIndex:1];
}
...
```

(In this scope, `text` is the last character they entered in the keyboard)

This code works fine, until I press a third character. After a very long time of trial and error, I found that it is because the variable `lastTwoChars` is getting released, and becoming a different object.

I cannot figure out how to keep the object from being deallocated and changing to another object. I've tried to `retain` the variable, but either I'm doing it wrong, or that won't work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The methods you are using do, indeed, return a new `NSString` object.  Are you using ARC or MRC?

Comment: @Droppy Whatever the default is. I never configured it to be different.

Answer (score -1):

Alright. I finally figured it out. Thanks to Droppy for hinting at the problem.

I fixed it by retaining the new strings:

```
if (lastTwoChars.length < 2) {
    lastTwoChars = [[lastTwoChars stringByAppendingString:text] retain];
} else {
    lastTwoChars = [[lastTwoChars stringByAppendingString:text] retain];
    lastTwoChars = [[lastTwoChars substringFromIndex:1] retain];
}
```

I didn't know that `stringByAppendingString` and `substringFromIndex` were creating new `NSString` objects, so thanks again to Droppy.

EDIT: I thought this may be a memory leak, but Droppy confirmed it was.

This is my new code:

```
if (lastTwoChars.length < 2)
{
    lastTwoChars[lastTwoChars.length] = (unichar) text;
}
else
{
    lastTwoChars[0] = lastTwoChars[1];
    lastTwoChars[1] = (unichar) text;
}
```

Comment: So now you've got a memory leak...  If you always want the last 2 characters then why not use `static unichar lastTwoChars[2];`?

Comment: @Droppy I didn't think of that, thanks. I edited the answer. Does that look about right?

Comment: No, not at all.  You need `[text characterAtIndex:index]`, where you need to calculate `index`.

Comment: @Droppy I ended up figuring that out earlier. It works now. Thanks for the help.